# Laravel mail with accent in subject

Tags: php, email, laravel

I have a service sending mails.

My problem is the subject in the title contains accents, but they're not showing up in the mails.

When for example I put in:

```
->subject ( 'Olvid&oacute; de Contrase$ntildea' );
```

In the mail the subject appears like this 'Olvid de Contrase'

It doesn't show the ó and ñ letters.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are using HTML entities. I think you should just use the UTF8 characters. Laravel uses Swiftmailer under the hood, and that should handle the encoding correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I find a solution, and is this

```
->subject(utf8_encode( 'Olvidó de Contraseña' ));
```

Works Perfect! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Subject is an email header. And headers may only contain ASCII characters.

So you have to encode your headers with base64 (B) and quote-printable (Q).

```
$to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'Subject with non ASCII ó¿¡á';
$message = 'Message with non ASCII ó¿¡á';
$headers = 'From: example@example.com'."\r\n"
.'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers);
```

Read more about RFC 1342 (Representation of Non-ASCII Text in Internet Message Headers): http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1342/